# Ionic.platform.exitApp() does not fire scope (on) destroy

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

We are having trouble shutting down our polling services on app exit and on app pause.
In the controllers I added

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
 $interval.cancel(<pollingIntervall>);
});
```

But the destroy signal does not fire if I call

```
ionic.Platform.exitApp()
```

nor if the app gets paused (hardware home button).

If I add

```
$rootScope.$destroy();
```

before I call ...extiApp() all scopes receive the destroy signal. But that doesnt work if the user is closing the app by using the hardware back button.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Platform.exitApp() is just a wrapper around Cordova's window.navigator.app.exitApp() method.  It doesn't do anything else.

As far as I know, you'll need to listen to the actual Cordova events like pause & resume.  The docs for Cordova's events can be found at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html.

Comment: Indeed I can receive the pause event, but I'm missing a "close" or "exit" event since "pause" is not fired if the user is closing the application with the hardware back button.

Comment: Can you use the backbutton event to handle this case?

Comment: Only partly:
If the user then pauses the app (hardware home button) and closes the app later (e.g. in settings->running apps) The scopes still won't get the destroy signal and the services will keep polling.